# 2D advice for nullpointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

I apologize in advance, I am a java noob.

I have this in a statement

```
if(a==0 && b<4)
{
value = ((elev[a][b]-elev[a+1][b])*0.00001* double "variable" ) ; 
}
```

So my main question is would the following....

```
(elev[a][b]-elev[a+1][b])
```

return an int value (assuming that the array was initialized and populated with int values, and that for a==0 and b<4 none of the references are null.

Sorry in advance if this is silly.  Please don't feel inclined to comment, but help would be appreciated.  I haven't done a lot of this java stuff.

When i populated the array, I printed it's contents to make sure I was populating correctly, and everything is where it should be...

Alas, I get a null pointer error wherever that (elev[a][b] - elev[a+1][b]) is first referenced....yet i know that the values are being put there.

Next question. When i populate an array,  if i want to reference the values,

```
while(input.hasNextInt())
           {
            elev[i][j] = input.nextInt(); <-- this is how i was doing it 
                        }
```

of elev[][]... do i need to say

```
elev[i][j] = new input.nextInt();
```

or is how i was doing it sufficient. When i populated an ArrayList from a file I had to use the "new" prefix So i was trying to figure out why i would get a null there.

Like i said I did print the array after reading it from the file and it printed out everything was in its place.

Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**
ok sorry for simplicity sake i didn't put in the actual code of "value"

it is actually

```
double randKg = getRandKg(avgKgNitrogen[z]); 
 double gradient = 0.00001

double under = ((randKg *(elev[a][b] - elev[a+1][b]) * gradient));
```

**2nd Edit**

This is the code for how i populated.

```
try{
                File file = new File(filename);
                Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

                int rows = 30;
                int columns = 10;
                int elev[][] = new int[30][10];

                for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                    {
                        while(input.hasNextInt())
                        {
                            elev[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                        }
                    }

                }
                input.close();
            }
            catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error opening "+filename+", ending program");
                System.exit(1);

            }
```

**3rd edit**
So i am getting the null pointer here.....

```
(elev[a][b] - elev[a+1][b]) > 0 )
```

Which is why i originally asked.  I have printed the array before when i populated and everything is where it should be.

Comment: yah thats cool, thanks for your reply.

Comment: as for the data type of value it is a double from another method

Comment: Sorry Thakare, I edited post to make it more clear.

Comment: yeah, am using a for loop to add and subtract at the position (of a different array) based on the elevation difference from the array that was populated from file

Comment: Please post your FULL code and FULL stacktrace.

Comment: And I suggest you to System.out.print each variable you are going to use in the line you suspect to trigger the NPE, and thus you can know which one triggers the NPE.

Comment: `(elev[a][b] - elev[a+1][b]) > 0 ) ` should not compile, it has mismatched parenthesis... (Point of this sarcastic comment is: showing partial code and asking why it crashes is pointless.)

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to add new sections when you edit a question at SO. Just edit the question as a whole to have complete info in the right order. Edit history is visible to all, if someone wants to see what was edited, and earlier comments becoming obsolete with edits is normal.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception because double "variable" does not indicate to any integer or double value. Compiler is just trying to convert String 'variable' into double which is not possible. So, try eliminating the Double Quotes from "variable". Moreover you have not declared the data type of value variable.

Comment: Sorry, I put that in there just for reference sake 
it is a double value that is from another method 
double randKg = getRandKg(avgKgNitrogen[z]);
is what value is...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring other problems in your code (covered by other answers), here's about your actual question:

If the code

```
if(a==0 && b<4) {
    value = (elev[a][b] - elev[a+1][b]); 
}
```

crashes with `NullPointerException`, it means `elev` is null. Assuming `a` and `b` are of type `int`, then there is no other way this can generate that exception (array out of bounds exception would be different). There are two options for the cause:

1. You execute above code before you do `int elev[][] = new int[30][10];`, so that `elev` still has the initial null value.
2. `elev` in the crashing line is a different variable than `elev` in initialization shown in the question.

And in you code, it seems to be 2. You create local `elev` in the initialization. It goes out of scope and is forgotten. You probably should have this initialization line in your method:

```
elev = new int[30][10];
```

And then you should have *a class member variable* instead of local variable in a method:

```
private int[][] elev;
```